# Website content cutoff & Images not responding Mobile Web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have had this problem for a while. Everything I have done to make my images responsive and contain in the parent element fails. My images get cutoff, they do not center, and zoom to smaller screens. Also, my homepage has a left margin space I can't seem to fix. I would like my content centered, and zoomed properly on small screens. My full sized background image is also not filling the whole background on smaller screens. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('span.nav-btn').on('click', function(){
$('#menu').toggle();
})
$(window).resize(function(){
if ( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
    $('#navigation.showing').removeAttr('nav-btn');
}
});
});//end ready
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="bg">
<div id="container" class="homepage">
<div id="header">
<p align="center"><img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="Lost Tourist Logo" 
width="517" height="269"/> </p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<span class="nav-btn"></span>
<ul id="menu" class="showing">
<li> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/menubar.png" alt="menu bar icon" 
width="122" height="118"/></a>
<p align="center">Home</p></li>
<li><a href="beers.html"> <img src="images/menubar.png" alt="menu bar icon" 
width="122" height="118"/></a>
<p align="center">The Brews</p></li>
<li><a href="events.html"> <img src="images/menubar.png" alt="menu bar icon" 
width="122" height="118"/></a>
<p align="center">Events</p></li>
<li> <a href="crew.html"><img src="images/Crew.png" alt="crew" width="122" 
height="118"/></a>
<p align="center">Crew</p></li>
<li> <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/Payphone_menubar.png" 
alt="contact" width="122" height="118"/></a>
<p align="center">Contact</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;

}
.bg {
background-image:url(images/CityScape.jpg);
height:100%;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
#container {
height: 900px;
width: 900px;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
}
#navigation ul li {
margin: 25px;
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation ul li p {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
margin: 5px;
}
#content {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
width: 900px;
height: auto;
background-color: #09F;
border: thin solid #000;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 25px;

}
#content table {
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: #06F;
width:550px;
}




#content table p {
text-align: inherit;
display: table-row;
vertical-align: middle;

}
#content img {
position: relative;


}
#content h1 {
padding: 5px;
}

#navigation {
clear: both;
height: auto;
width: auto;
margin: 0px;
}
#content p {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: large;
margin: 5px;
}
#footer p {
margin: 5px;
}

#footer {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 15px;
border: thin solid #000;
background-color: #09F;
}
#header img {
padding: 25px;
}
```

My CSS for small screens:

```
    /*smart phones*/
/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
```

and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

```
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
```

and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

```
}

/* ----------- Galaxy S5 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
```

and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

```
}





body, html {
height: 100%;
marging 0;


}

.bg {
background-image:url(images/CityScape.jpg);
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;

min-width:100%;
}


#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
padding:5px;
margin:0px;



}
#header img {
position: relative;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
max-height:100%;
overflow: hidden;

}
#navigation {
font-size:large;
height: auto;
width:100%;
float:none;
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto;
padding:10px;





}

#navigation ul {
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
}




#menu {
float:none;
margin:auto;
display:none;
width:100%;
max-width:360px;
position:relative;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
text-align:center;

}
.nav-btn {
width:100%;
background-color:#09F;
text-align:center;
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:15px 10px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:large;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
height:100%;
}
.nav-btn:after {
content:url(images/mobilemenu.png);

}
    #menu li {
    width:100%;
    font-size:large;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#09F;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    border:#000 medium solid;
    float:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;

}

#menu img {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:90px;
height:90px;
position:relative;

}

#navigation ul li {
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
float: none;
overflow: hidden;


}

#menu li a {
width:100%;
display:block;

}





#content {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:auto;
padding:10px;



}

#content background img {
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
}


.socialmedia {
width:30px;
height:30px;
max-width:30px;
max-height:30px;

}




.bigfoot {
width:50px;
height:50px;
max-width:200px;
max-height:200px;
}

.mail {
max-height:110px;
max-width:110px;
}


#content img {

height:auto;
width:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
margin:5px;
}

#content table, tbody, th, td, tr {
display:block;
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;

}



#content table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width:auto
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
position: relative; 
min-width:100%;



}

#content td {

min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
position:relative;
width:auto;
}
#content table p {
display:block;
text-align:inherit;
vertical-align:middle;
max-width:100%;
}


#footer {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a link where we can see an example of the result? It might be easier to answer that way.

Comment: Yes, my website: http://www.losttouristbrewing.com/

Answer (score 2):

first, add a basic box-sizing property

```
*{box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}
```

2) remove margin from #container

3) remove margin from body

4)for responcive img use `img{max-width: 100%;height: auto;}`

Comment: Thank you. I did the above, and still have so much left side space, and images are  still pushed against parent container.

Comment: @gmm29 can you give a fiddle with your problem? or image how it must be?

Comment: On my website the homepage is pushed to the right of the screen with all this empty margin on the left. The images are also cut off on my pages. I ran a debugging console test and no scripting or CSS errors.